# All functions respecting $F(x)=\sin^2 x+f(x), \forall x\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=1$ that admit the antiderivatives $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
such that
$$F(x)=\sin^2 x+f(x), \forall x\in \mathbb R$$

**EDIT** (inspired by julien's work):

Since 
$$F(x)=\sin^2 x+f(x)$$
$$F(x)-f(x)=\sin^2(x)$$
multiply both side by $e^{-x}$, and then
$$e^{-x}F(x)-e^{-x}f(x)=\sin^2(x)e^{-x}$$ 
$$(F(x)e^{-x})'=-\sin^2(x)e^{-x}$$
$$\int (F(x)e^{-x})'\mathrm{dx}=-\int \sin^2(x)e^{-x}\mathrm{dx}$$
and the rest of the story is easy.

Comment: All continuous functions?

Comment: Have you studied how to solve ODEs like $F'(x) = F(x)-\sin^2 x$?

Comment: @user7530: I'm not that good at ODE, and I'd like to avoid this way if possible.

Comment: Note that if $f$ satisfies the equation, then $F$ is $C^1$ like $\sin^2x$, so $f$ is actually $C^1$. This hard not to differentiate this and solve the resulting first order linear ODE... But we'll try.

Comment: @julien: that seems right. Do you think it's helpful? Do you ponder over a way that uses this fact?

Comment: Actually, I think I found a way to write it by doing ODE without doing ODE explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find a particular solution $f_0$.

Then observe that $f$ is a solution if and only if $g=f-f_0$ is solution to 
$$
G=g\qquad g(0)=1-f(0).
$$
for some antiderivative $G$ of $g$.

Now consider
$$
h(x)=e^{-x}G(x).
$$
Clearly
$$
h'(x)=e^{-x}g(x)-e^{-x}G(x)=e^{-x}(g(x)-G(x))=0 \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
So (MVT) $h$ is constant equal to $h(0)=G(0)=g(0)=1-f_0(0)$.

Hence $G(x)=(1-f_0(0))e^x$ so 
$$
g(x)=(1-f_0(0))e^x\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Hence there is exactly one solution to your problem, namely:
$$
f(x)=f_0(x)+(1-f_0(0))e^x \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Can I let you find a particular solution?

As André points out, you should look for a solution of the form
$$
f_0(x)=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x).
$$

Comment: Thanks (+1). Your work really inspired me! :-)

Comment: @user7530 No. Since $f(x)=F(x)-\sin^2x$, $f$ is differentiable, hence continuous. Note also that then $F$ is $C^1$, hence $f$ is $C^1$, etc...So the equation forces actually $f$ to be $C^\infty$.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The following suggestion is ODE motivated.

Note that $\sin^2 x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x$. Look for a solution  of the shape $f(x)=A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x+Ce^x$.

Comment: thank you (+1). My teacher said to me: "solve it without ODE". Surely, there must be a way.